# When are wp redirect methods safe to hook?

Tags: hooks, wp-redirect

I'm currently using `wp_safe_redirect()` in a callback function that is hooked into the [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter. I would like to do my conditional statements here to determine whether the template should load based on user capabilities. If not, then redirect to home page. It looks like this:

```
public function my_load_template( $page_template ) {

    if ( is_singular( 'my_cpt' ) && is_user_logged_in()
        && current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ) {
        return plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) .  'public/templates/single-my_cpt.php';
    }
    else {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Hooked using `add_filter( 'template_include', my_load_template' );`

In the case that it redirects, I get a browser error saying the site "redirected you too many times." I suspect this may be a result of running the redirect during this filter.

I would like my conditional check for user capabilities to be as early as possible. So when is it safe to follow that with a redirect? Should I be doing a capability check and redirect in the single post template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been going through action hooks and the earliest I've gotten it to work properly with my conditions for user and page type conditions is the `wp` action. Although, I am currently hooking it into [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect#Performing_a_redirect) as it seems most appropriate and intended for this purpose according to the codex:

> It is a good hook to use if you need to do a redirect with full
>   knowledge of the content that has been queried.

Any attempt to redirect in an action that precedes `wp` in the order of [actions run] would cause problems, such as not being able to modify headers or the "redirected you too many times" error.